# Shell programming - reading and outputting the contents of found file

Tags: bash, shell, find, echo

I'm attempting to create a shell script that will find a file, read that file, output the contents of that file and sorting the contents by username. The text file that the script is finding will simply contain a list of usernames and processes. For examples the usernames will look like jsmith2 etc. When the end result is outputted, contents need to be sorted by username. In other scripts I have used the --sort user to sort the output alphabetically, but that was when I used the ps aux command.

This is what I have so far and am now a bit stuck. Any help would be great. Apologies, I am a bit of a newbie.

```
#!/bin/bash
find -name 'user*'| while read fname; do
   echo "$fname" --sort user
done
```

Comment: You have to tell us what you mean by "sorting the contents by user", i.e., you have to specify the format of that file.

Comment: An actual sample of the file would be more helpful than an English-language description of its format, particularly for anyone who wants to test their answer.

Comment: For instance -- is each line like `username proc1 proc2 proc3`?

Comment: I don't actually have much of a sample file, this is for an assessment and the teacher simply informed us that the file would contain usernames and processes. I believe each process for the user will either be on a new line or look like your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what you've written verbatim, assuming the first column in each file is the username:

```
find . -name 'user*' -exec cat '{}' + | sort
```

This concatenates all files found by `find` into a single stream, and pipes that stream to `sort`. By default, `sort` sorts starting at the beginning of each line -- so if the username is the first item in each line, this will perform precisely as desired.

Comment: Perfect! I'm so sorry I couldn't give more information, but I was running on limited info myself. Thanks so much for your help.